# Background Upload is not working in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession, background-fetch

I was trying implement a code where a API will be called shortly after a file has been uploaded into AWS server but it must be in background mode. Whereas the AWS sdk manages uploading file into their server in background mode but the following code is not working.

**ViewController.swift**

```
func upload(_ mediaData:Data){

   //AWS method to upload a file
   AWSS3UploadImageData(mediaData!, strImageName: "person.jpg", strContentType: "img/*", { (isSuccess, result, strMessage) in
         if isSuccess {
              let arrPost = result as! [[String : String]]

              //Call custom webservice
              VaultUploadWebService.shared.callVaultUploadWebService(Params: arrPost)
         }
         else {
             print("Unsuccess")
         }
   })
}
```

**VaultWebService.swift**

```
class VaultUploadWebService: NSObject {

    static let shared = VaultUploadWebService()

    var savedCompletionHandler: (() -> Void)?

    func callVaultUploadWebService(Params: [[String : String]]) {

        startRequest(for: "www.example.com", param: Params)
    }


    func startRequest (for urlString: String, param: [[String : String]]) {

        let identifier = "com.com.background" + "\(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)"
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier:identifier)
        let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

        let url = URL(string: urlString)!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 180)
        request.httpMethod = "post"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")      
        do {
           let paramsData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:param, options:[])
           request.httpBody =  paramsData

           session.uploadTask(withStreamedRequest: request).resume()
       }catch {
        print("JSON serialization failed: ", error)
        return
       }


        //Also tried using the following but no luck
        /*guard let documentDirectoryUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else { return }
        let fileUrl = documentDirectoryUrl.appendingPathComponent("Persons.json")
        let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
        do {
          let jsonData = try jsonEncoder.encode(param)
          try jsonData.write(to: fileUrl, options: [])
        }
        catch let error {
          print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        session.uploadTask(with: request, fromFile: fileUrl).resume()*/

    }

}


extension VaultUploadWebService: URLSessionDelegate {
    func urlSessionDidFinishEvents(forBackgroundURLSession session: URLSession) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.savedCompletionHandler?()
            self.savedCompletionHandler = nil
        }
    }
}

extension VaultUploadWebService: URLSessionTaskDelegate{

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {

        if (error != nil){
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "error")
        }
        else{
            print(task.response)
        }
    }
}
```

And last.. **Appdelegate.swift**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession identifier: String, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

   let id = identifier as NSString
   if id.contains("com.amazonaws") {
       AWSS3TransferUtility.interceptApplication(application, handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession: identifier, completionHandler: completionHandler)
   }else{
       VaultUploadWebService.shared.savedCompletionHandler = completionHandler
   }
}
```

But this delegate method never gets called whereas its being called for AWS upload. I think that's the main reason why background `uploadTask` not working for me. Stuck for 2 days. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: May be UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier can help you out, please read about this.

Comment: Have you enabled background mode in Capabilities?

Comment: @TarasChernyshenko  : Yes

Comment: Did you check if the URL you are trying to hit in the background is getting hit in the method startRequest and you are getting any response?

Comment: Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/22703658/1057689

Comment: @AkshaySunderwani ; Yes its getting hit and this method `func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?)` is being called.

Comment: @Al_ : Checking

Answer (score 2):

`uploadTask(withStreamedRequest:...)` is not compatible with background URL sessions. Use `uploadTask(with:request, fromFile:...)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`httpBody` is ignored if you create an upload task by `uploadTask(withStreamedRequest:)`. It requires to implement `urlSession(_:task:needNewBodyStream:)` delegate callback. For the case of background mode it doesn't suite. Try to use `uploadTask(with request: URLRequest, from bodyData: Data)` instead. Also it looks like `VaultUploadWebService` does not have any references to the `session` object. Try to store `session` as a member of `VaultUploadWebService`.

Comment: Tried `uploadTask(with request: URLRequest, from bodyData: Data)`...same result.

Comment: Have you checked that at least one of your requests has reached your server? HTTP proxy tools, e.g. Charles can help you with this. In other words the issue that your requests are not even executed or you just don't receive callbacks about their execution state (successful or failed)?

Comment: And as I pointed out in my answer, `session` object is probably deallocated just upon end of execution of `startRequest ` method, because `VaultUploadWebService ` doesn't have any references to it. Check this point, because it also may cause this issue.

Comment: Yes, because   `func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?)` is being called.

Comment: I'm checking if `session` is being deallocated upon end of execution of startRequest

Comment: What print log output did you get in `func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?)`?

Comment: Unfortunately when I tried to log in background it doesn't print. It only print when I came to foreground.

Answer (score 0):

Background download events don't fire on a simulator. You can only test this on a real device.

Comment: I tried, no luck. But the interesting thing is AWS iOS SDK's upload method works in simulator also.